Filters in tabs of dynamic forms | Lightning Record Pages
I have a Lightning record page that displays different tabs. If I wanted a tab to be displayed for a specific user once that user adds an account to their account team, could this be done from there? For example, I thought there could be a field that identifies the user on the account object, so that if the user that stores that field is equal to the user that was added to the account team of the account (the account field would be updated with a record trigger flow), then that user could go on to see the other tab that, before not having the doctor in their portfolio, they did not have.
I tried from the tab filter but it does not accept variables in the value, such as: User.name or something like that.
I hope I explained myself. If anyone has any suggestions that can provide me with a solution or some clarity, I would greatly appreciate it. Greetings
